# Python 'get_text()' not working

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to compile the following code from parsing html but i come up with an error:

```
import string, urllib2, urlparse, csv, sys
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from ast import literal_eval

changable_url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All%20In%20One/E%20Series'
page = urllib2.urlopen(changable_url)
base_url = 'http://www.asusparts.eu'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

selects = []
redirects = []
model_info = []

#Opening csv writer
c = csv.writer(open(r"asus_stock.csv", "wb"))
#Object reader
cr = csv.reader(open(r"asus_stock.csv", "rb"))

print "FETCHING OPTIONS"
select = soup.find(id='myselectListModel')
selects.append(select)
print selects.get_text()
```

The error is:

```
print selects.get_text()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

How am i able to pass this error? Thanks.

Comment: How does it not exist?

Answer (score 2):

You are running the `get_text()` function on `selects`, which is a list. Lists don't have that function.

Should you not be running it on `select` itself? Or what about each element in selects:

```
for item in selects:
   print item.get_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this error a lot.

This has to do with what variable you are applying `get.text()` to; `get_text()` is a function that works with Beautiful soup. So you have to re-soup select:

```
select2 = BeautifulSoup(select, "lxml")
```

`"lxml"` can be replaced by whatever parser you're using.  If this doesn't work try turning select into a string first- and then doing the above variable function.

Answer (score -2):

You need get an element in a list.
Try `selects[0].get_text()` and it should work.